# How smooth does a shower pan need to be?

Tags: shower

Does the pre-slope pan have to be smooth?  Mine is kind of rough in some places has a sand roughness.  If it does have to be smooth what is the best way to smooth it? I thought of mixing some cement powder and just put a very thin smooth top.  I bought some concrete adhesive to put in between the top coat and pre-pan.

What do you think?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

It only needs to be smooth enough to get the water in the pan to go to the drain, and not poke a hole in the pan while working the mud bed for the tile over it. If there are any sharp ridges even a trowel can scrape those down flat enough to be of no concern.